# Undefined control sequence in .bbl file

Tags: errors, bbl

I've got the problem that everytime I run my .tex file I get the error `undefined control sequence`. It shows me that the error is in line 406 in my `.bbl` file which is a blank line. Does anyone know, where this comes from?
Many thanks in advance.

Here is the part of my `.bbl` file that is concerned. Line 406 is the blank line between the two `\bibitems`:

```
\bibitem[Spinrad et~al.(1963)Spinrad, M{\"u}nch, und Kaplan]{Spinrad1963}
H.~Spinrad, G.~M{\"u}nch, und L.~D. Kaplan.
\newblock Letter to the editor: the detection of water vapor on mars.
\newblock \emph{\apj}, 137:\penalty0 1319, 05 1963.
\newblock \doi{10.1086/147613}.
\newblock URL \url{http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1963ApJ...137.1319S}.

\bibitem[{Stanford University}(2016)]{Stanford2016}
{Stanford University}.
\newblock Lecture nr.13 paramagnetic relaxation enhancement, 2016.
\newblock URL
  \url{https://web.stanford.edu/class/rad226b/Lectures/Lecture13-2016-PRE.pdf}.
\newblock Zuletzt aufgerufen: 2018-09-19.
```

Comment: can you show us the complete error message?

Comment: It would help if you would mention which command is undefined - in case you can't see it, look in the log file.

Comment: @J.Eng That is probably only what your editor shows you. There should be more in the .log file.

Comment: A wild guess: what does happen if you add `\newcommand{\apj}{The Astrophysical Journal}` to your document?

Comment: @samcarter That solved it!! Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.Eng Good to hear that this solved your problem. For a complete list of macros, see e.g. here: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty